# Interface language for guest users

Tags: localization, user-interface, google-meet

When you are signed in to **Google Meet**, the language is according to your account preferences.

On a shared/public computer, for security reasons, you might use Google Meet as a guest, without signing in to your account. In this case, Google Meet seems to adopt the interface language according to the browser and OS settings.

I can't find a way to change the language, either on the invitation page, or after joining the meeting.

In the settings, you can only change the language for captions.

My default web search engine with `language site:support.google.com/meet` only brings results related to modifying the captions and not the interface.

Does anyone know a way to change the language via settings, or perhaps by modifying the invitation URL?

Comment: Please show what you tried including enough detail so other coul repeat the same stpes. Also share what you found in https://support.google.com/meet and why it didn't meet your needs.

Comment: @Rubén: For Google support, please, see the edit. Then, "In the settings, you can only change the language for captions" means that I looked to change the language in the Settings, beyond the webpage. And I don't know where else I could look.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I rarely say the following: please believe that I empathise 100% with you and others that come to sites like this.  I really understand the feeling of having done the best to write a question brief but complete and then someone appears saying that something is missing, unclear or whatever that doesn't give the answer or feedback that I'm expecting.  The comments provided aren't intended to be annoying are just looking to help that your question had better chances to stand out and prevent to be automatically deleted.